# Java Categories like Obj-C?

Tags: java, oop, objective-c-category

When programming using other people's classes, you often find that they didn't quite anticipate your needs and you have to use a sequence of several steps all over for what should be a one step operation.

IE, you're using a class that indexes objects, and so has a `getObjectAtIndex` method and a `getNameOfObjectAtIndex` method, but you want to access objects by name instead of index, so you have to write a loop that uses the `getNumberOfIndexes` method and loops over each, checks the name against the name you want, returns the index, and then you use access the object at that index.

If you need to do this frequently, to keep your code tidy you should refactor.

In Obj-C, the solution is to write a category. You can just add a new `getObjectWithName` method to that class (and all of its subclasses) without having to subclass or encapsulate it.

In Java, I haven't yet found a particularly great solution. Instead I've been writing helper functions that aren't invoked on any object but require the object to be passed in. Basically I have a method with function notation, which can be difficult to read.

To be clear, this isn't a class I wrote and I don't have the source code to it. Some other code is creating and returning it, so making a subclass doesn't help as I can't change that code that returns it to return my subclass instead. I could encapsulate it, but that seems even less elegant than what I'm already doing.

Does anyone know of a way I can achieve functionality similar to Obj-C's Categories in Java?

Comment: In Objective-C it is also best to write helper methods, not to create categories in an Apple supplied class. What you gain with a category is one fewer argument, what you loose is clarity, pollution of the class instance methods and the method is being added as you mentioned to all instances that do not use the method. If you feel compelled to create a category prefix the method name with a unique identifier. Keep in mind that Apple may add a method of the same name in the future and them havoc will pursue.

Comment: An alternative to categories is to write `Class` methods in a helper class, then no instantiation of a class is necessary.

Comment: @Zaph - I hadn't considered the possibility that Apple could add a method of the same name in the future. I'll be sure to use prefixes as you suggest to avoid future name collisions. I strongly disagree with you though on the other drawbacks. All of that is moot when faced with the fact that readability trumps all else until it's proven that performance needs additional consideration.

Comment: I also put readability above performance unless/until performance is proven to be a problem. For me a method added to an Apple class is less clear than a `Class` method in a helper class because it is self contained and clear it is not base functionality of the Apple class.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare It goes beyond potential collisions.  When you extend system classes with categories, you are creating an *interleaved model* where your code is effectively interleaved with the system code.  This is considerably more complex and difficult to maintain than a *layered model* where your code sits on top of system code.   The layered model may lead to a few more lines of code, but it'll be easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @bbum: for that very reason I avoided this practice when first working with iOS/OS X. But categories on Apple's classes are so frequently used, I wonder if it might now be considered an overlearned idiom: that is, when we see categories named with non-Apple prefixes, we instantly perceive them as client-layer code. That only deals with the semantic issue, admittedly, but that does seem to be your main objection.

Comment: @cris There has been any number of bad/lazy patterns perpetuated across the community.   Said categories are certainly convenient and, frankly, there is something to be said to optimizing for your ship date over code maintainability, but there is a significant maintenance cost to using such.

Comment: @bbum Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what the problems are. AFAIU: (1) namespace pollution (technical issue), (2) separateness of software layers (conceptual/semantic issue). For (2): if idiom (even a bad one!) is entrenched enough that we _automatically_ see it as existing in the client layer, doesn't that obviate the problem? Just a thought. I share your suspicions, but with less confidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, Java developers most commonly use helper methods for this sort of thing. It's flexible and relatively modular, and really not so bad as you think.

A related technique is to use a *wrapper object*; a class that contains an instance of the class of interest, implements the same interfaces, and delegates most calls through to the contained instance, perhaps adding some methods along the way. Some IDEs (IntelliJ IDEA, certainly) have built-in tools that make creating this sort of delegating wrapper painless. Then whenever you receive a reference to an instance of the class of interest, you construct an instance of the delegator around it before doing any further processing.

If you really want something more interesting, there is always [Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/aop.html), which refers to tools and techniques for injecting new code into existing code based on various criteria at runtime. It is possible that you could use AOP to do something like this; for example, by adding an interface to a class, and a method that implements it. You'd have to cast the objects to the interface at compile time to use the method.

Comment: I didn't realize IntelliJ provided such functionality. Even so, a wrapper still seems like an ugly hack to me. Anytime the class changes, your wrapper needs to change, too.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Hence AOP. If you use runtime AOP, that deals with that possibility. Or, you could use compile-time AOP and make sure you always rebuild when a dependency is updated.